# Is it possible to query selected properties in firebase object?

Tags: javascript, firebase

[image]

Is it possible to query the selected fields in the Firebase object?
For example, Can I query just a name and address from the object?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#web

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no.
Firebase always retrieves full nodes.
You can read all data but extract only the properties you are interested in.